# Running multiple threads in Python and closing them when done

Tags: python, python-multithreading

(I am quite a newbie in Python....)

I have a method that I need to run in parallel.

It is running nice, but when the method ends, nothing happens... and the next line is not called.

```
q = Queue.Queue()
for driver in drivers:
   t = threading.Thread(target=DoSomeStuff, args=(args.build, driver))
   t.daemon = True
   t.start()
s = q.get()
print s
```

Comment: Which is the "next line" that isn't executed? What is `q` here?

Comment: can you share more of it?

Comment: just updated the question

Comment: what python version?

Comment: The version is 2.7

Comment: How about a [mcve]? Otherwise, the code you haven't shown is a complete mystery.

Answer (score 0):

The working piece of code is:

```
drivers = ["a", "b", "c"]
threads = []

for driver in drivers:
    t = threading.Thread(target=DoSomeStuff, args=(driver))
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()

for t in threads:
    t.join()
```